# Refering to a xml layout inside a widget's class

Tags: android, xml, layout, widget

So, I am trying to get reference to a xml layout from the class of a simple widget I made.

So ,my widget contains an ImageView and two TextViews.I will add the code for this widget, just so no one gets confused.

```
public class Item extends LinearLayout{

TextView tv1,tv2;
ImageView img;


public Item(Context context,int resid, String t1, String t2) {
    super(context);

    setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);

    setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    img = new ImageView(context);
    tv1 = new TextView(context);
    tv2 = new TextView(context);

    img.setBackgroundResource(resid);
    img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    img.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(200, 200));

    tv1.setText(t1);
    tv1.setTextSize(15);
    tv1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    tv1.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(250, 100));

    tv2.setText(t2+"lei");
    tv2.setTextSize(15);
    tv2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    tv2.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(250,100));

    tv1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    tv2.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

    addView(img);
    addView(tv1);
    addView(tv2);
}
```

So, as you can see, there's a clickListener added for each "Item".What I want to do ,is to be able to refer to a xml layout that is a second activity ,so that I can manipulate what is in this layout from within this widget.

The second activity's class:

```
public class Final extends Activity {

LinearLayout fl;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.final_layout);
    View rootView = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);

    fl = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fl);

}
```

}

The XML file for this second activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/fl"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

</LinearLayout>
```

So, once again, to sum up, I want to be able to add stuff to this second activity ,from the class Item ,but I am not able to take reference to the XML layout coresponding to the second activity.

Comment: I'm not following you here.. you want to reference a second activity from a Widget created in the first activity? when the second is not created yet?

Comment: Practically,I don't care for the activity.I just want to refer to know if it's possible to refer to the XML file without the activity being created.Because all I want to do,is too add some views to the LinearLayout in this XML file, nothing else.

Comment: It Is something like http://trickyandroid.com/protip-inflating-layout-for-your-custom-view/ what you mean?

Comment: I think he wants to remove and add things in a second activity but he´s messed up the "concept" of Android View or something... and it won´t work.. it won´t. Sorry to say. Layouts are, somehow "static" although you can change and add things in runtime, each time they´re loaded into an activity they´re just as they´re in design time and gotta be changed by code

Comment: The point is that I am not really sure this works,but yes, what eduyayo said is what I have in mind.Practically,Each time I click one of my "Item" ,I add it to a second activity's layout.Basically,I can do this already by passing around the variables ,but I was wondering if I can do it directly from the widget by refering to a XML layout WITHOUT the activity being created. @mmark -not mate,that link is useful but is not what I needed.

Comment: then keep goin´with your first approach. It is the correct "workaround". There´ll be people telling you to add donnowhat to a database and then load from whatever... but... whatever works... haha. But just know you´re trying to find a new problem you did not have!!!

Comment: I will be working with databses later on ,for this project ,but at this moment I just wanted to check if this works this way ,even though it doesn't make sense from a View's point of...well view ,haha.Comes to my mind now that wouldn't have made sense to do what I wanted to, as it was pointless later on.Thanks for the comments, helpful I guess.

Answer (score 0):

So,practically ,the only way to do this, is to pass variables through the onclick method.

What I am doing right now is this: I get two String variables and one Int.Strings being used for the text wrote in textViews and int for the resource ID for the imageView's backgroundResource, pass them to the second activity and use them there to re-create the Item.

If anyone needs more details on this, leave a comment here and I'll do my best to help.